После установки пакета wireguard система не грузится
Всем привет. Есть проект в котором использую Orange PI One, на него установлен Armbianю. В качестве подключения по VPN было принято решение использовать WireGuard. После того как установил WireGuard ( sudo apt install wireguard ), делаю reboot - ОС "ложиться"- только переустановка. В чём может быть проблема? Один проект уже запущен и на нём всё работает, сам оранж, флешку - менял. Новый Armbin качал, различные утилиты для создания образа. На одном работает, на другом ломает систему. Пробовал и как с конфиг файлом так и без него. Какие варианты можно ещё попробовать для решения проблемы?
